# In Oracle, how to select specific row while aggregating all rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement that I need to both aggregate all rows by id, and find 1 specific row among the rows of the same id. It's like 2 SQL queries, but I want to make it in 1 SQL query. I'm using Oracle database.
for example,table t1 whose data looks like:

```
id   |  name  | num
----- -------- -------
1    |  'a'   |   1
2    |  'b'   |   3
2    |  'c'   |   6
2    |  'd'   |   6
```

I want to aggregate the data by the id, find the 'name' with the highest 'count', and sum all count of the id to 'total_count'.
There are 2 rows with same num, pick up the first one.

```
id   | highest_num | name_of_highest_num |  total_num |  avg_num 
----- ------------- --------------------- ------------ -------------------
1    |      1      |          'a'        |     1      |     1
2    |      6      |          'c'        |     15     |     5
```

Can I get this result by 1 Oracle SQL query?
Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, name, num ) AS
SELECT 1, 'a', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'b', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'c', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'd', 6 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX( num ) AS highest_num,
       MAX( name ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY num ) AS name_of_highest_num,
       SUM( num ) AS total_num,
       AVG( num ) AS avg_num
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id
```

**Output**:

```
ID HIGHEST_NUM NAME_OF_HIGHEST_NUM TOTAL_NUM AVG_NUM
-- ----------- ------------------- --------- -------
 1           1 a                           1       1 
 2           6 d                          15       5
```

Comment: I like this answer better -- +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use some analytic functions.  Something like this should work

```
select id,
       num highest_num,
       name name_of_highest_num,
       total total_num,
       average avg_num
  from (select id,
               num, 
               name,
               rank() over (partition by id
                                order by num desc, name asc) rnk,
               sum(num) over (partition by id) total,
               avg(num) over (partition by id) average
          from table t1)
 where rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the idea is correct, but when I ran in SQL developer, it tells me ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 16. The sum() & avg() seems have some problem

Comment: @L.L - D'oh, yup.  Fixed the bug

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using `row_number` in a subquery with `conditional aggregation`:

```
select id, 
  max(num) as highest_num,
  max(case when rn = 1 then name end) as name_of_highest_num,
  sum(num) as total_num,
  avg(num) as avg_num
from (
  select id, name, num, 
    row_number() over (partition by id order by num desc) rn
  from a
  ) t
group by id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/69ec0/2)

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. The result is correct. And it gives me another idea of how to deal with such problems.